# OpenID authentication through Steam

Tags: node.js, security, authentication, openid, steam

I've spent the better part of the day trying to figure out how OpenID works. My goal is to set up a simple site where, upon clicking a login button, users are taken to a Steam login-page, where they are prompted for username and password. After successfully logging in, the user is redirected to a page on my domain, where I collect the query string parameters. They look like this:

```
{  
    "openid.ns": "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0",
    "openid.mode": "id_res",
    "openid.op_endpoint": "https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login",
    "openid.claimed_id": "https://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/7656119[0000000000]",
    "openid.identity": "https://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/7656119[0000000000]",
    "openid.return_to": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/resolve",
    "openid.response_nonce": "2018-12-01T14:49:46Z30hhn2/[someTEXTendingIN=]",
    "openid.assoc_handle": "1234567890",
    "openid.signed": "signed,op_endpoint,claimed_id,identity,return_to,response_nonce,assoc_handle",
    "openid.sig": "[someTEXTandNUMBERSendingIN=]"
}
```

What I am unable to solve though, is the actual authentication issue. I'm not sure what to do with this data. I want to have my own database where I store more information about the user, such as friends, messages, currency etc. For this, it is very important that I can verify that someone didn't just take this request body, change their ID for another and in that way access their account.

I'm pretty sure [these](https://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-1_1.html) are the relevant pieces of documentation, but it still isn't clear to me. How am I supposed to authenticate the user with this data?

I've omitted some values in this post that I fear could be bad to share. These placeholders have been outlined with brackets `[]`. Also, that `assoc_handle` is really `1234567890`, which kind of puts me off, since according to the OpenID documentation, it is used for determining the signature.

To be clear: this page where credentials are collected is not run by me, but is the official OpenID sign-in page for Steam. Steam is a gaming platform. https://steamcommunity.com/dev/ for reference.

Answer (score 2):

For Steam authentication in nodejs you can use Passport.

Passport is an authentication library that works best with Express-based web application.

There is a steam-strategy that can handle your steam authentication.

Check passport [here](http://www.passportjs.org/)

And this is the Repository for [Steam strategy](https://github.com/liamcurry/passport-steam#readme). There is an example folder that you can see how to setup your Steam authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use my package for this. I've taken openid and rewritten it (or wrote from scratch) to modern TS. You're welcome ;)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/steam-lightweight-openid